# How to determine ellipse parameters such as center, orientation from four points on the ellipse?

Tags: python, parameters, ellipse

I have four points from an ellipse diagram and I want to know the ellipse parameters such as center, orientation. The points are (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), (x4,y4).

```
#Sample points for x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4
#409.3333,544,1064,372,656,180,818.6666,737.3333
#405.3333,549.3333,857.3334,217.3333,493.3333,165.3333,766.6666,601.3333
#474.6667,364,1006.6666,369.3333,722.6667,133.3333,729.3333,600
```

Code to generate ellipse parameters using equation

```
for i in dat:
    line=i.strip()
    splt=line.split(',')
    x1=float(splt[1])
    y1=float(splt[2])
    x2=float(splt[3])
    y2=float(splt[4])
    x3=float(splt[5])
    y3=float(splt[6])
    x4=float(splt[7])
    y4=float(splt[8])
    Amatrix = matrix([(y1-y2)/(x1-x2)-1,(y3-y4)/(x3-x4)-1]) #Amatrix
    Bvector = [((y1-y2)/(x1-x2))*(x1-y1), ((y3-y4)/(x3-x4))*(x3-y3)]
    A = sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2);
    B = sqrt((x3 - x4)**2 + (y3 - y4)**2);
    center = (Amat.I)*Bvec;
    orientation = atan((y1-y2)/(x1-x2));
    print(center)
```

I am getting 4 points as center but I'm supposed to get 2 points only.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for making it more meaningful...

Comment: Amatrix vs A vs Amat ??? Bvector vs B vs Bvec ??? Please show the code that you executed to calculate the centres.

Comment: Four input points isn't enough - there are symmetry cases that allow infinite families of ellipses.  Conversely some sets of four points may not lie on any ellipse - do you want a best fit?

Comment: It seems that if you do not have any additional information you need 5 points. In this case you can substitute these points in the equation a11*x**2+a22*y**2+2*a12*x*y+2*a13*x+a23*y+a33 = 0 and find coefficients aij from system of linear equations.